# rstrip() has no effect on string

Tags: string, python-3.x

Trying to use rstrip() at its most basic level, but it does not seem to have any effect at all.

For example:

```
string1='text&moretext'
string2=string1.rstrip('&')
print(string2)
```

Desired Result:
text

Actual Result:
text&moretext

Using Python 3, PyScripter

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someString.rstrip(c)` removes all occurences of `c` at the *end* of the string.  Thus, for example

```
'text&&&&'.rstrip('&') = 'text'
```

Perhaps you want

```
'&'.join(string1.split('&')[:-1])
```

This splits the string on the delimiter "&" into a list of strings, removes the last one, and joins them again, using the delimiter "&".  Thus, for example

```
'&'.join('Hello&World'.split('&')[:-1]) = 'Hello'
'&'.join('Hello&Python&World'.split('&')[:-1]) = 'Hello&Python'
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect. Mind clarifying what you're doing with the index ([:-1]) ?

Comment: Removing the last member of the list.